# Path Planning on a 3d point cloud

Tags: point-clouds, robotics, motion-planning

I have a 3d point cloud of a location on which I am trying to design a path planner for a mobile robot. Can anyone please guide me towards the right approach to take in solving the problem. For the point cloud, I have the coordinates of the obstacles on the map (their x,y,z positions). I am trying to solve the problem as a stand-alone general purpose planner for a mobile robot without using ROS.

My current stumbling block lies in the theoretical aspect as well since the fact that the point cloud consists of just x,y,z points, how is a path planning algorithm like A* run on such types of data where you can't define a general grid like that for a 2d case with each grid cell as a node? I have the coordinates of the obstacles on the map (their x,y,z positions).

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can provide me with some guidance on how to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem. The first step should be calculating the normal vectors of the point cloud. Then, the path can be calculated based on the normal vector.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).